# Find $\lim\limits_{x\to0}{e^{x^2}-\sqrt{1+2x^2} \over x^2e^{2x}+2\ln{\cos{(x+x^2)}}}$

Tags: limits

I am looking for
$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}{e^{x^2}-\sqrt{1+2x^2} \over x^2e^{2x}+2\ln{\cos{(x+x^2)}}}$$
Using the suggestions below, we transform
$${1 \over e^{x^2}+\sqrt{1+2x^2}}\times{e^{x^4}-2x^2-1 \over x^2e^{2x}+2\ln{\cos{(x+x^2)}}}$$
Now, we focus on the second fraction.
$$e^{2x^2}-2x^2-1 = 2x^4+o(x^4)$$
$$e^{2x}=1+2x+{4x^2 \over 2}+{8x^3 \over 3!}+{16x^4 \over 4!}+\dots=1+2x+2x^2+{4\over3}x^3+{2\over3}x^4+o(x^4)$$
$$x^2e^{2x}=x^2\left(1+2x+{4x^4 \over 2}+\dots\right)=x^2+2x^3+2x^4+o(x^4)$$
$$\cos(x+x^2)=1-{(x+x^2)^2 \over 2}+{(x+x^2)^4 \over 4!}+\dots=1-{x^2+2x^3+x^4 \over 2}+ {(x^2+2x^3+x^4)^2 \over 24} +\dots=1-{x^2\over2}-x^3-{11 \over 24}x^4+o(x^4)$$
$$\ln{\cos(x+x^2)}=\ln{\left(1-{x^2\over2}-x^3-{11 \over 24}x^4+o(x^4)\right)}=\left( -{x^2\over2}-x^3-{11 \over 24}x^4+o(x^4)\right)-{\left(-{x^2\over2}-x^3-{11 \over 24}x^4+o(x^4)\right)^2\over2}\dots=-{x^2 \over 2}-x^3-{7 \over 12}x^4 +o(x^4)$$
$$x^2e^{2x}+2\ln{\cos(x+x^2)}={5 \over 6}x^4+o(x^4)$$
The whole second fraction is
$${2x^4+o(x^4) \over {5 \over 6}x^4+o(x^4)}={2+{o(x^4)\over x^4} \over {5 \over 6} +{o(x^4)\over x^4}}$$
and the whole limit is
$${1 \over 2} \times {2 \over {5 \over 6}}={6 \over 5}$$

My question now is: How do we know that it is $o(x^4)$ we need to look at and not, say, $o(x^2)$ or $o(x^3)$? Is there a relatively easy way to "see" this from the get go?

Comment: Have you used L-hospital here?

Comment: $ (e^{x^2})^2 = e^{2x^2}$ not $e^{x^4}$

Comment: You should expand untill the fourth order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have solved the question correctly via Taylor series. Your main concern is about figuring out the number of terms needed in the Taylor series to evaluate the limit correctly. Well the simple answer is that you need to have as many terms as are sufficient to give a non-zero coefficient in both numerator and denominator. Suppose you used terms only till $o(x^{2})$ then both the numerator and denominator will have the form $0x^{2} + o(x^{2})$. If you do the expansions till $o(x^{4})$ you get numerator as $x^{4} + o(x^{4})$ and denominator as $(5/6)x^{4} + o(x^{4})$. It is the non-zero coefficients which finally remain in the limit evaluation and lead to the answer $6/5$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$\sqrt {1+2x^2}=1+x^2-\frac{x^4}{2}(1+\epsilon_1 (x)) $$

$\ln(\cos(x+x^2))=\ln(1-2\sin^2(\frac {x+x^2}{2})) $
$$=\frac {-1}{2}(x^2+2x^3+x^4 (1+\epsilon_2 (x)) $$

You will find zero.